# RPC call with web3

Tags: web3js, json-rpc

I am using `extend` on web3 to use the `evm_unlockUnknownAccount` on ganache whit this snippet

```
const localWeb3 = new Web3(ganache.provider( {fork : web3ws.currentProvider} ));
localWeb3.extend({
  methods: [{
      name: 'unlockUnknownAccount',
      call: 'evm_unlockUnknownAccount',
      params: 1
  }]
});
```

then I console log the `localWeb3` and see the new method. When I tried to use the new method it returns a pending promise, so i added `await` the issue is the `evm_unlockUnknownAccount` doesn't return a value `bool`.

```
const result = await localWeb3.unlockUnknownAccount(address)
console.log('unlock?', result) // stuck waiting long time
```

How do I do rpc call correctly with web3? or is there other easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solution is working for me:

```
web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
        jsonrpc: '2.0', 
        method: 'evm_unlockUnknownAccount',
        params: [address], 
        id: new Date().getTime() 
      }, console.log);`
```